# jQuery: Changing Value of input onCLick

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery, I want to click on different buttons and get text input in the text field from the button.

```html
<ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
    <li><button type="button" id="p1" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl btn-block">$15</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" id="p2" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl btn-block">$25</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" id="p3" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl btn-block">$50</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" id="p4" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl btn-block">$75</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" id="p5" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl btn-block">$100</button></li>
    <li>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="form-control-donate controls">
                <input name="textinput" placeholder="$ Other Amount" class="form-control" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you want it - do it, what is the problem?

Comment: Sorry , How can I do it ?

Comment: @ShuvoHabib by learning jQuery basics.

Comment: Guys please don't be evil.. Maybe the answer will be a start for him to understand how jQuery works..

Answer (score 2):

```
$('button').click(function(e){
  $('input[name=textinput]').val($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Matei Mihai . I can't upvote . I regret :(

Answer (score 1):

May be something like this:

```
$('#p1,#p2,#p3,#p4,#p5').on('click', function() {
    $('input.form-control').val($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Thanks ! Solved previously.